# Unexpected behavior using Bootstrap-Table and Javascript in Django (inline editable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [bootstrap-table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) with inline editable plugin to create a bootstrap table for a list of laptop. My goal was to apply changes to my csv file after users make changes to the table **like this example (Product Category: Laptop)**

[image]

I have created a javascript function below to send Ajax data to my Django server.

```
// ajax to server
$(function () {
     $( "#table" ).on("click" , 'button',function(event){
      var selected_item = getSelectedRow(); //this will return selected row object
         console.log(selected_item);
         $.ajax({
        type: "post",

        url: '/update/',
        data: {
            'item': JSON.stringify(selected_item)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            }
        });
     });
});
```

Below is the output from my console log

> (pcategory has been changed to Laptop2)

[image]

However, when I try to get the data from Django. It gave me the output below, which **(pcategory was not changed to Laptop2)**

```
{'webcam': 'WebCam', 'lannum': '2', 'condition': 'Refurbished', 'video2': 'GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]', 'memorybanks': '8G 2133MHz/8G 2133MHz/', 'cpus': '1', 'customernotes': '', 'lanmodels': 'Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller/WLAN QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter/', 'internalnotes': '', 'pline': 'Alienware', 'sku': 'LEN-LT-TPEdge-03BV001', 'cddvd': '', 'hddcapacity': '0.0G', 'coresthreads': '4 | 8', 'sound': 'Sound-Yes', 'pmodel': '15 R2', 'resolution': '1230x1000', 'ptype': 'Minitower', 'grade': 'GradeB:R2-Ready for Resale', 'touchscreen': 'Yes', 'hddqty': '0', 'pcategory': 'Laptop', 'processor': 'i7-6700HQ  2.60GHz', 'memory': '16G', 'serialnum': 'BFYNM72', 'video1': 'GM204M [GeForce GTX 970M]', 'hddmodels': '', 'manufacturer': 'Alienware', 'motherboard': 'Alienware 15 R2', 'batch': '03BV', 'hddserialnum': ''}
```

My Django view function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_page(request):
    file_path = os.path.join(CSV_BASE_DIR, CURRENT_BATCH, '{}.csv'.format(CURRENT_BATCH))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = json.loads(request.POST.get('item'))
        pprint.pprint(item)
        overwrite_csv(file_path,item)
    else:
        print('no data back!')
    return HttpResponse('yes')
```

I noticed when I changed the input again. The value will get changed to laptop2. It seems like it didn't save the value in the way I expect it to be. I'm wondering is there any way my Django server would get the same value as soon as I click on the check mark?

Thank you all in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data source is Same for both listing and updating.